# Curve Editor — Move 2 Handles the same time

Tags: edit-mode, graph-editor, fcurves

I am quite new to blender and started out to do some animation with shape keys. That is working quite fine so far and now I would like to make that whole thing a bit more vivid.

Therefore I would like to tweak the Interpolation curves in the Curve Editor, what is in principle working as expected, there is only one thing that bugs me. Please see the image below:

[image]

Marked in red are two curves which are somehow identical in shape, but each of them is for a different property, what is just as wanted.

I would like to edit both curves, so that they stay identical. I can select both anchor points and drag them around, but I cannot select two handles at the same time.

Is there any way to do this? If not, how can I copy the setting of one point (anchor and control points) from one to another?

Thanks in Ahead!

**[UPDATE]**

After some hours of trying and searching the web I just came over drivers, as mentioned in the comments. That lead me to what I am after and gave me ever more flexibility.

Comment: Exactly what a driver does, choose one property that you are going to keyframe, and drive the other(s) with it.

Comment: I might have missed something, so is it not possible to edit these two curves at once, so that they stay equal in shape?

Comment: Added as a comment as it doesn't answer the question re handles which I'm not sure about, rather suggests another approach.

Comment: which? Let me know please…

Comment: Have you tried selecting them with box [B] or circle [C] select?  You can't select the handles this way but you can select the keyframes and use [S] and [R] to move the handles.

Comment: [B] did not work for handles, but for the anchors

Comment: It worked for what I was trying to do, which it was adjusting the fade of several curves at the same time. I think you just forgot to mention that you had to use the circle selection tool (shortcut C) in order to use middle mouse button to deselect. I just thought this hint would help other people. Thanks for the gif!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To select and move 2 curve handles at the same time you can use simple way which means selecting everything first, and then deselecting what shouldn't be moved.

1. Select all the curve points which should be edited, set the curve handles type to *Free* with <kbd>V</kbd> > *Free*.
2. With <kbd>MMB</kbd> deselect curve points and those curve handles which should stay untouched.
3. Move only one half of curve handles, not moving another.

[image]

This works in a similar manner as with editing Bezier curves in 3D View. You can scale, grab those handles etc.

The disadvantages:

- It may be hard to tell exactly which handle belongs to which curve point so in order to select / deselect them correctly.
- In case of many curve points to process this may be inefficient.

Comment: Thanks for that answer, it works as described. Unfortunately it could deliver the result I was after…

Answer (score 1):

Posting for posterity, but mass, deselecting can be done more easily (at least now).  First, drag a box in the graph editor to select the keyframe points you want.  Then Ctrl-drag a box to deselect the points and handles that you don't want to move.